# How can i make the following pattern in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

`A`

`B B`

`C C C`

`D D D D`

`E E E E E`

I don't know, how to print alpahbets

Comment: As you are new member, i am just giving a hint ( procedure ) as the answer but you have to implement it on your own...

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: `1.upto(5) { |i| puts (64 + i).chr * i }`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Its not for `RUBY` nor for any other language, its just a flow :

Print alphabets like :

```
for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
{
    System.out.println(ch);
}
```

1. Now initialise counter `i = 0`
2. Increment i++ in every loop.
3. Print the current outer loops current `char`, i times

Comment: This question was specifically tagged ruby, so that's why you're probably getting downvoted

Comment: This is a good answer using pseudo code, encouraging the op to find their own solution.

Comment: @SagarPandya I disagree.  What was presented here is a procedural approach when the target language is object-oriented and has strong functional leanings.  This is not idiomatic for a question that specifies Ruby, as you can see by contrasting this with ray's answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following to work it out:

```
('A'..'F').each.with_index(1) { |letter,index| puts "#{letter} "*index }
```

Alternatives include making the ranges variable:

```
lower_limit = 'A'   # could be read in rather than wired
upper_limit = 'F'   # ditto
(lower_limit..upper_limit).each.with_index(1) { |letter,index| puts "#{letter} "*index }
```

or using an array with `join` to get the spaces without introducing a trailing blank:

```
(lower_limit..upper_limit).each.with_index(1) { |letter,index| puts Array.new(index) { letter }.join(' ') }
```

Comment: You don't need an array, just use a range `('A'..'Z')`. Also use `each.with_index(1)` to avoid having to do `i + 1` on each iteration.

Comment: @SagarPandya Thanks edited, That helped, I just did not noticed it in hurry

Comment: I think the interpolation of `n` isn't needed, and if you called your variables `letter, index` that might add a little clarity. Good solution though!

Comment: @JayDorsey The interpolation is a clean way of getting the spaces, but I agree that renaming the variables would add clarity.

Comment: @pjs You're right, I didn't account for the spaces between lines (I didn't even really "see" them when i looked). I just assumed it was copy/paste noise rather than an integral part of the output. But, per the OP, it does have spaces so the interpolation would be an easy way to do that

Comment: @JayDorsey Yup I always keep clarity (rails does suggest although) while working on project, here missed, edited. Interpolation was added only for spaces.

Comment: @pjs sorry for being late, you can go and edit my answer for addition.

Comment: Thank you all of you it's work, and sorry for my late response.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like -

```
(1..5).each do |index|
  (1..index).each do
    print (64+index).chr
  end
  puts "\n"
end
```

What it does -

1. (1..5) - Run a loop with index starting from 1 up until 5.
2. (1..index) - run another loop so for each of the above loop, it runs from 1 up till index, which will be controlled from the (1..5).each loop.
3. (65).chr -> A, (66).chr -> B and so on..
4. puts "\n" to add a new line

That will give you the output -

```
A

BB

CCC

DDDD

EEEEE
```

If you want to add anything additional to whatever you are printing you can do something like -

`print "#{(64+index).chr} - random text"`

`#{}` construct will allow you to write ruby interpret-able code within a string block`

Note: `#{}` only works when you use double quotes :)

Comment: You had gone too deep, check my answer and space between two characters will be much better.

Comment: @ray - yeah, yours is cleaner, since the OP looked like a beginner, I thought simple loops would be easy to understand

Comment: Better to get beginners used to Ruby idioms such as iterators and closures as quickly as possible, particularly since they are often cleaner once a person moves past the "but it's different!" phase.